# Elasticsearch shard file size has to be less than JVM size

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elsticsearch blog post pointed out that the absolute maximum shard size should be around 30-32BG:

https://qbox.io/blog/optimizing-elasticsearch-how-many-shards-per-index

Can anyway share some insight on why is there such a constraint? How does shard size has to be smaller than the JVM heap size?

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks,